# Where can I find information about Nuance's new Nina SDK?

Tags: sdk, nlp, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

Nuance made a major announcement on 8/6/2012 about their new Nina technology, but the SDK does not seem to be available. I don't even find any documentation beyond marketing stuff (video etc.). Does anybody know how to use this SDK, or when/where it will be available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They made the announcement but it doesn't mean the product will be available soon for a wide audience. They just started one partnership to prove the technology work and you need to be a very big client in order for them to return your calls.

Luckily, there are other speech recognition and NLP providers out there. You should better check the ones who have the product available.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. Which NLP/Virtual Agent SDK providers would you recommend ? For speech I'm aware of ispeech.org.

Comment: I never worked at intelligent speech agents, I work on a speech recognition toolkit CMUSphinx. But some names which are famous in industry are: EJtalk http://www.ejtalk.com, SmartAction http://smartaction.com/, TalkAMatic http://talkamatic.se. From opensource solutions you can check Olympus-RavenClaw http://wiki.speech.cs.cmu.edu/olympus

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main site is http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home

Comment: Dragon Mobile is the old, "raw ASR" API, not the new Nina SDK. Thanks anyway ! :)